# i am running my flutter in vs code and i have an error while trying to use the dropdownfield package

Tags: flutter, dart

import 'package:dropdownfield/dropdownfield.dart';

the error:

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:dropdownfield

: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
../…/material/text_form_field.dart:97
TextFormField({

i tried adding the -no sound null safety- to the test and run Flutter Run Additional Args ,Flutter test Additional Args files but it is still giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggest the package doesn't support null safety, and the package is old and not maintained. so instead of disabling the null safety try to look for another package that would save u later a lot of truble. Always look for a maintained packages and keep up with new features.

Check for example [dropdown_formfield](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield) [dropdown_textfield](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_textfield) or forms packages like [formz](https://pub.dev/packages/formz) ... Moreover, the default dropdown provides great of ability to customize it

Comment: thanks let me try it out and i will get back